# How to fix no sound in some video & audio files played in Google Chrome and Opera browsers?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio, opera

I am trying to fix an issue where there is no sound when I play some video & audio files in both Google Chrome and Opera browsers. It seems both Google Chrome and Opera have the same issue because the same exact files have no sound in both browsers. I am wondering what is common between Opera and Chrome browser where both are experiencing the same issue.

The same files play fine in Firefox, IE 11 and Edge browsers.

**Some items that play with no sound in Chrome browser & Opera**
Hangouts voice messages play with no sound.
Lynda.com training videos play with no sound.

Here is a YouTube video that plays with no sound.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0W91FrTlYk

Most YouTube videos play fine with sound, but there are many that play with no sound. I often have to switch to another browser just to hear the video.

I would really like to fix this issue so I don't have to keep switching browsers.

Does anyone have ideas of something I should try?
Is there some codec I need to re-install or fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Steps that fixed my issue:**

- Open Creative Audio Control Panel
- In Speaker Configuration section,
  change 7.1 Speakers to 2/2.1 Speakers.

This immediately fixed my issue and I did not even need to reboot. All the previous video and audio files I was having an issue with play fine now in Google Chrome & Opera browser.

Reading [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/27ho7u/some_youtube_videos_have_no_sound) helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you, not the same solution, but my audio for my suondblaster audigy fx card under the speaker/headphones tab didn't have anything selected. I selected headphones and resaved my profile and it finally fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I hope the person you want to have your babies does, in fact, have them.

Comment: For me it was in Realtek HD Audio Manager, changing 5.1 audio to stereo. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Solved: as astonishing as it sounds, windows "sound problem solving" fixed it.

-> disable sound device sound enhancements (creative x-fi device in my case)

-> set default audio format (someone else has to elaborate on this)

works for your video example i had no sound earlier.

---

OLD POST

Same issue, same software, same OS. Occurs since anniversary update.

update: K-Lite codec doesnt help.

interesting reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/27ho7u/some_youtube_videos_have_no_sound/?st=iu2wia2i&sh=5360921f

"Not sure if you're in the same position, but if you have a 5.1 surround setup like me this might be worth your while. I got the exact same problem.
What's special about the video you've posted as an example is that it runs through the center speaker.
My speakers come with a button that converts 2 channel audio to 5.1, a feature I leave on when watching YouTube videos. When I encounter that video, it's silent as the only audio is coming from the center speaker, not left or right.
Basically you want to disable any virtual surround features when watching such vids. Either a button on your speakers or audio settings."

Comment: The reddit post link you added led me to my solution. Thank you.

Comment: the underlying problem appears to invlolve creative settings carrying over in the win10 anniversary update process (at least in my case).